# Should comparing a secret hash be sufficient for validating PayPal IPN message?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

When a user start the checkout process I store a payment entry in the database and assign that payment a `payment_hash`. The payment hash is passed as `custom` parameter in the API for PayPal.

When the IPN is sent to my server, I check if the `payment_hash` from `custom` field matches a payment in my database then deal with that payment (update status, fulfill order etc)

Question. Am I doing it the right way? Or should I be also comparing the amount, user email, or another field?

My hash is a random generated alphanumeric string (64 chars) and is unique per each payment attempt/entry.

Basically here's the code logic I am currently using (Considering I got the $_POST response and validated it with Paypal servers)

```
$payment_hash = $_POST['custom']; // We will use to find the payment in our database.
$payment_id = $this->get_payment_id_by_hash( $payment_hash );
if ( $payment_id && $payment_id > 0 ) {

    $payment = new MC_Payment( $payment_id );
    $payment->update_payment( $_POST );

}
```

When adding a payment entry I generate the hash like this:

```
$this->params['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM'] = 'pt_' . mc_rand_hash();
```

Thanks for the input.